# Loading HTML string using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am loading HTML passed as string into HTMLAgilityPack document as below.

```
 HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
 html.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
 html.LoadHtml(htmlText);
 HtmlNode document = html.DocumentNode;
```

After loading the document.InnerHtml shows up with &quot(sample below) for all the quotes.How can I avoid this?

```
<span style=\"\\&quot;MARGIN-LEFT:\" class=\"\\&quot;form_title\\&quot;\" _20px5c_22_=\"\">MyText</span>
```

I would want the sample to be displayed as below.

```
<span class=\"form_title\" style=\"MARGIN-LEFT: 20px\">MyText</span>
```

From the obtained "document" I have to loop and find elements(using fizzler component). But with "&quot" appearing I am not able to do so.

Comment: What is the original HTML like?

Comment: As @Oded said: What is the original HTML page you're trying to parse? You could try using `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(document.InnerHtml)` method on `System.Web` assembly.

Comment: HTML is complex. It's of a dynamic page with many hidden controls. If i copy it to text file it's about 150kb. I don't see a way to attach it here.

Comment: @San - What about the _relevant_ part - say the span you have shown as an example - can you post the actual source as seen on a browser?

Comment: Issue got solved after I added - HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");     html.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;

Comment: @san - please answer yourself so the question is marked as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue resolved after adding

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form"); 
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
```